# How to prevent touchend event after dragend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-events

I'm working on a mobile site and struggling with events firing when I don't want them to.

For the sake of simplicity, it's written something like this (in jQuery):

```
el.on('touchend', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    // fire an ajax call
};
```

However, sometimes a user would hit the item when scrolling the page, causing the ajax request to fire (thus changing the page state).

I couldn't think of a way around it (`ev.stopPropagation()` didn't work) , so I decided watch for `dragstart` and `dragend` events.

```
el.on('dragstart', function() {
     el.off('touchend');
});

el.on('dragend', function(ev) {
     ev.stopPropagation(); // <-- seems to do nothing
     // add back the event above (the function is set to a var)
});
```

If I alert inside the `touchend` callback, I get confirmation that the `touchend` event did in fact fire after I stopped dragging.

Does anyone have any idea how to prevent any other events from firing? I'm hoping I'm just being blind and missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop an event from firing, you can only prevent the default behavior for that event from happening.

If you're worried about the state of your page changing before the touchend event fires, you should just change your function to check for and then account for the state change.

Answer (score 0):

I think in a case like this you should use

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```